# How to pass data from one controller to another controller in my case

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to pass a data into my controller by using `State Provider`.

I have something like this

app.js

```
  $stateProvider       
        .state('test', {
            url: '/te',
            views: {
                '': {
                    templateUrl: 'test.html',
                    controller: 'testCtrl'
                },
                data:{
                    testValue:true
                }
            }
        })
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('mainTestCtrl', function($scope) {
    //I need to be able to get the testValue from here.
})


app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
    var testValue = $state.current.views.data.testValue;
})
```

I can't really provide the state provider for `mainTestCtrl` because I need testValue to be `true` only when `testCtrl` is called. I need a way to pass testValue to mainTestCtrl. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: At the point where `testCtrl` is instantiated, is `mainTestCtrl` already instantiated itself?

Comment: @Marc yes mainTestCtrl will be instantiated before testCtrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both controllers have the same level (*a.e not parent-child*) you can use `$rootScope.$broadcast`.

Demo 1 <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1603/)</kbd>

*Beware!!!*

> be sure that 2<sup>nd</sup> controller is initialized before you send `$broadcast`. Otherwise noone will listen.

---

But I would use service that will store `testValue` and every controller can fetch it back:

Demo 2 <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcUm6/38/)</kbd>

Comment: Why does a parent-child relationship preclude the use of `$rootScope.$broadcast`?

Comment: @MarcKline for me, its not good style to use frequently `.$broadcast` under `$rootScope`. In case of parent-child, parent send broadcast by using his own scope but not `$rootScope`

Comment: I see... I thought you were saying that it wasn't possible (which I would have objected to). I guess you're just saying you wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: btw, if the service will only ever be necessary for this one value, a `value` service would be more concise: http://jsfiddle.net/39Sy5/